# mysql query to select two columns from same table

Tags: mysql, shell

Below are the sample tables I'm working on

**Table 1**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REV         ║ REDO ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 43453453345  ║  2   ║
║  1 ║ 2433423423   ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ 23423423     ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ 5566533      ║  2   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I need to select **REV** from **table 1** using  **KID** and **REDO** and put in **table 2** so that I get a result like below.

**Table 2**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╗ 
║ KID║  REDO1       ║  REDO2     ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════║ 
║  1 ║ 43453453345  ║2433423423  ║
║  2 ║ 23423423     ║   5566533  ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

ie all **REV**'s with **REDO**=1 must come under **REDO1** and **REV**'s with **REDO**=2 must come under **REDO2**,all **KID** is not unique.
How to accomplish that with just plain mysql? Please help me

Comment: Do you want to display redo1 and redo2 according to redo number in table1?

Comment: @Ullas I need to select `redo1` and `redo2` using both `kid` and `redo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to produce the required result set:

```
SELECT KID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN REDO = 1 THEN REV) AS REDO1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN REDO = 2 THEN REV) AS REDO2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY KID
```

The above uses *conditional aggregation* in order to place all `REV` values that are associated with a `REDO = 1` value under `REDO1` output field, and all `REV` values that are associated with a `REDO = 2` value under `REDO2` output field

If you want to insert the result of the above into `Table2`, you can use a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT KID, MAX(CASE WHEN REDO = 1 THEN REV END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN REDO = 2 THEN REV END) 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY KID;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cefb/1)

Comment: Thank you,but I'm using `COALESCE` because I'm selecting from multiple `table1`'s. How should I include that?

Comment: @AafreenFirdaus On which fields is `COALESCE` used ?

Comment: on both the `REV`'s because I'm searching 4 different tables with the same structure as the `Table  1`

Comment: @AafreenFirdaus You can quite simply use `COALESCE(REV, 'whatever')` instead of `REV` inside the `MAX(CASE ...`.